# bootstrap-multiselect drop down taking too long render

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `davidstutz's bootstrap-multiselect` dropdowns in my MVC razor view,

I have a total of 6 dropdowns in my page.
The `count of the list` for all the dropdowns combined is around `8000`.
It is taking nearly 2 minutes for me to load the entire page because of the backgroud bootstrap-multiselect dropdown script.

Is there a way to improve the performance , if it is not possible is there a `better multiselect dropdown`  with most of the features of `davidstutz's bootstrap-multiselect`?

For reference go through [this](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options) for all the features provided in this dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an AJAX mulitple select.  This will help it works like a charm for me.. it will only load what you get from your query, thus ignoring 8000 rows you can select only what you need when you need it...

https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager

scroll down to where it says "Using tag manager in conjunction with typeahead.js"

Comment: May be i was not clear with my question, when i said 8000 rows, i  meant 8000 rows shared across all the 6 dropdowns. i.e. I have State ,District, Village etc. Village is the lowest denomination, i.e. each district may have upto 600-1000 villages.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr Trust me  use the plugin it will help.